# Exception from Tracker recompute function: Error: Bad index in range.getMember:

Tags: meteor

After Meteor Update (not sure from which probably old version), but following re-subscribe with a different livehistory triggers the described error.

Meteor.subscribe("amon", livehistory, type)

```
Exception from Tracker recompute function: Error: Bad index in range.getMember: 80
    at DOMRange.getMember (http://clochette.cow.lu:3000/packages/blaze.js?efa68f65e67544b5a05509804bf97e2c91ce75eb:586:11)
    at http://clochette.cow.lu:3000/packages/blaze.js?efa68f65e67544b5a05509804bf97e2c91ce75eb:2572:43
    at Object.Tracker.nonreactive (http://clochette.cow.lu:3000/packages/tracker.js?517c8fe8ed6408951a30941e64a5383a7174bcfa:513:12)
    at Object.eachView.stopHandle.ObserveSequence.observe.changedAt (http://clochette.cow.lu:3000/packages/blaze.js?efa68f65e67544b5a05509804bf97e2c91ce75eb:2567:17)
    at http://clochette.cow.lu:3000/packages/observe-sequence.js?2fd807ea171ead273b9e6458607cb226012d9240:284:21
    at Function._.each._.forEach (http://clochette.cow.lu:3000/packages/underscore.js?0a80a8623e1b40b5df5a05582f288ddd586eaa18:164:22)
    at diffArray (http://clochette.cow.lu:3000/packages/observe-sequence.js?2fd807ea171ead273b9e6458607cb226012d9240:270:5)
    at http://clochette.cow.lu:3000/packages/observe-sequence.js?2fd807ea171ead273b9e6458607cb226012d9240:147:9
    at Object.Tracker.nonreactive (http://clochette.cow.lu:3000/packages/tracker.js?517c8fe8ed6408951a30941e64a5383a7174bcfa:513:12)
    at http://clochette.cow.lu:3000/packages/observe-sequence.js?2fd807ea171ead273b9e6458607cb226012d9240:121:15
```

Comment: I got this too since I turned off reactivity in one of my template helper functions - any solutions yet?

Answer (score 0):

I do not have the solution, but I too encountered the same error, and was able to solve for my case, so posting it, hoping it helps someone. The cause was use of `.length`. I had a large array (name of array: data), and to make it short (decrease length of arrray), I was assigning `data.length = 5`, which was somehow causing the error, and meteor helper did not work as expected. **Removing that line worked for me**, and I accomplished shortening of array by a for loop, and storing first five elements in a different variable.

Answer (score 0):

For me creating an empty array with fixed size (in a helper) was the culprit:

```
x = new Array(n).
```

Replacing it with:

```
x = Array.apply(null, Array(n)).map(function () {})
```

solved the issue.
Magic...

Answer (score 0):

When I had this error I was using a "hard-coded" array. The error was caused by an empty array member (two commas to separate objects instead of a single comma). Fixing this resolved the issue. So - check your data.

Answer (score 0):

This may also happen if you remove some element in the middle of an array with `delete` and later use this array reactively. The problem is related with incremental cycles over the array's elements that may address this recently deleted element. Use `splice` instead of `delete`.